# How to add new product into dabase from Ajax Request

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

I am trying to insert new product from a edit form via Ajax request, I am returning all values inserted however instead adding new product it's adding first product on the list. what am I doing wrong?

this is my Ajax request:

```
$(document).on('change','.qty',function(){


    var id = $("#inv_id").val();
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var name = tr.find(".name").val(); 
    var price = tr.find(".price").val(); 
    var qty = tr.find(".qty").val(); 
    var total = tr.find(".total").val(); 

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/product',
        data: {id: id, name: name, price: price, qty: qty, total: total, '_token':$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        success: function( data ) {

            console.log(data);

        },
            error: function(data){
            alert("fail");

            }
    });
```

});

this is my controller

```
public function product(Request $request){



        $prod = new Product;
        $prod->invoice_id = $request->id;
        $prod->name = $request->name;
        $prod->price = $request->price;
        $prod->qty = $request->qty;
        $prod->total = $request->total;
        $prod->save();


    return response()->json(['responseText' => 'Success!'], 200);




}
```

I have tried using Product::create([]); but it's not working either. it adds a copy of the first product the id returning is the id coming from invoice id.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong?
Ajax response data or inserted values into db?

It seems to me that your ajax call doesn't returns anything about the product you've created.

Maybe something like this?

```
public function product(Request $request) {

    // ...

    return response()->json($prod->toArray(), 200);
}
```

Comment: inserting values into database. I get 500 (Internal Server Error).

Comment: if I return $request->all I get everything i entered in the form. however it's not adding into the database. always getting 500 (Internal Server Error). any idea why? thanks for taking your time

Comment: I have used a loop as well, no luck